# if Linux is open source does that mean I can see the code of ( Ubuntu 22.04.4 )

Tags: 22.04, source-code

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Recently I was wondering if I can go to the OS files and edit them.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the definition of "open source". But what do you really mean? Can you edit your question to make it more specific? What files? What part of the OS? Do you want to read, or edit and if edit, to what end? Do you then want the system to use your edited files? Please add some context here since as it stands, the only answer is "yes but don't use 'goto'".

Comment: Enable the source repository (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu), then use `apt source` to download the source code for the package(s) you're interested in.

Comment: You can _technically_ edit files that are on _your_ machine.You can't "edit" Ubuntu files on your own (you would have to talk to a lot of other people before modifying the OS) but you can  [help develop](https://ubuntu.com/community/contribute/ubuntu-development) it.

Comment: Yes you can. I mean editing the source files and then compiling the whole package and install it on your computer. But, with all due respect, if you have to ask that question, I have have some serious doubt that's what you should do. So what's your final objective?